# Converting currency values - eurocents to euros with rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, currency, data-conversion

the application exports data to my DWH in **euro cents**. I need to convert these values to **euros** with **rounding up**. Euro cent data format is **int**

Here is a sample of the data in the table:

```
  CustID   Money   Date
  ===========================
  1        148180  2021-02-10
  2        520     2021-02-11
  3        50      2021-02-11
  4        25      2021-02-12
```

Well, the column **Money** that we know is in eurocents, which means that rounding to the correct value will be for CustID:

```
  1 - 1482 
  2 - 5,2 
  3 - 0.5 
  4 - 0.3
```

The point is that when the value in the **Money** column is only Eurocents, as in the case of CustID 3 or 4, I must also show this value, not just the number without the decimal point. So I need to set the conversion to this column to two decimal places. Do you have any suggestions?

### EDIT

I tried something like this, but the result is 1,481 with rounding down and without two decimal numbers.

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(148180/100 AS money), 1)`

Comment: I don't understand the rule. You want to round up euro cents to euros, so 148180 becomes 1482. Why then does 520 not become 6? Well, your result 52 is too big by a magnitude of 1, so this must be a mistake. But still, how can a result even have decimals when you round up to euros? I.e. why is it 0.5 and not 1; why is it 0.3 and not 1? There are two or three different rules you apply here. Please elaborate.

Comment: Im sorry @ThorstenKettner I misspelled value at CustID 2 it should be 5,2.

Comment: Still two rules. Why 5.2, 0.5, and 0.3, but 1482  and not 1481,8? One time you round up to euros and three times you round up to 10 cents. Why the different rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get from euro cents to euros by dividing by 100. Use `100.0` in order to avoid integer division in SQL Server.

You round up to the next integer number with `CEILING`.

Now to the display format. You want two decimal places. A number, however, does not have a particular number of decimal places. The number 1.2 is the same as 1.20 and still the same as 1.20000 in a SQL Server database.

If you want to display a number in a certain format, you need a function to convert the number into a string with the desired decimal places, the decimal character matching your culture (comma or point), etc. The function for this is `FORMAT`.

```
select custid, format(ceiling(money / 100.0), 'N2') as euros
from mytable;
```

The format `'N2'` is just an example. You can of course use a different format. Read about this here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ce85ce73e624d2b6bf9426b410be0fd

Comment: Thank you a lot Thorsten, you helped me to solve my problem !

Answer (score 1):

for output with digit numbers: divider value must be contains decimal or float, can u try like this ?

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(148100/100.00 AS money)), 1), '.00', '')
```

Comment: Thanks Karcan, I used it to my other problem with second currency ! :)